# What is the difference between employee and personnel?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I have been searching on how to use the following nouns personnel and employee in their proper meanings.

I always find that personnel refers to people employed in an organization , and employees are the people that work in a company. I don´t know how to distinguish one of another.

How could I use them in sentences?

Answer (score 3):

A basic difference is that [personnel](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/personnel?s=t) refers to many people and [employee](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/employee?s=t) refers to one individual.

Oftentimes, in a company, there will be a "personnel department" that handles employment, benefits, hiring, and other tasks related to the employees of the company.  "Personnel department" is also known as "Human Resources" or "HR." Some temporary employment agencies refer to themselves as a "personnel staffing solution."

In sentences:

1) My boss said that he appreciated having me as his employee.
2) During the holiday season, there is a normal reduction in personnel in most companies.

Comment: So, when I refer to personnel, I am talking about my employees in general. And employee, a one in particular.

Comment: @MoisésSoares Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @MoisésSoares If you like the answer, give it an upvote :)

Comment: it has just been done.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the question is about *Personnel* and *Employees* (plural of 'employee').

*Employees* are all the people that are **working under** a company.

While

*Personnel* are all the people **working for** a company.

This make a big difference.

Personnel include "Affiliates, officers, directors, employees, agents, contractors, consultants, vendors, internals, invitees and representatives".

While Employees doesn't include independent contracts but just "employees".
I suppose a freelancer can be considered personnel but not employees.

Comment: Strong first answer. Only suggestion I would make is to add a dictionary reference/link to your definitions.